# Navigating to android support library source from IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

When I'm working on an Android app, I can control+click on a function call in editor to navigate to the function source. This works well for classes in the project and classes in Android SDK. However, if I control click on a function call that is from an Android Support Library (say: android-support-v13.jar), I'm taken to a file that has the function signature but the contents say "compiled code".

I tried adding the path to the support library's source to Project Structure->Sources but looks like that didn't make any difference.

How do I set this up right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Navigate to `Project Structure | Libraries`
2. If you haven't already, create a library and add the android-support-v13.jar
3. In the same library, click "Attach Files or Directories..." and select the Android Support Library's src directory (`<android-sdk>\extras\android\support\v13\src`)
4. Add this library as a project dependency

Your library should look something like this:
[image: example settings]

Comment: One thing I'd like to point out is that for v13 support library, you'll also need to add v4 sources and it seems like v13 also includes v4 in it. For example, my project depends on android-support-v13.jar. When I added src only for v13, I was not able to navigate to source of NotificationCompat from the editor. I added v4 src as well and now I was able to naviage to NotificationCompat correctly.